# Mongo compare and import missing data

Tags: mongodb, database

I have a mongo server receiving data from servers behind an amazon LB, 2 days ago there was an error and part of the servers sent their data to an old mongo server that had a db of the same name, we realized that and fixed it back right away.

Now i have part of my data stored on the wrong machine.
What I need now is a way to compare the data between the 2 dbs (which each have 2 relevant collections) and insert only the missing data to the correct collection.

I do not care about the unique id mongo gives but i do need to compare by the field "uuid" that we create.

mongo version: 2.4.4

I am new to Mongo and any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. Follow these steps...
**1**  mongoexport and then mongoimport on the basis of fields on which you want to compare and import.

> 1. mongoexport --db db_name --collection collection_name --type csv --fields field1,field2,field3 --out /var/www/export.csv

once you get the exported CSV at the specified location. Open and remove unwanted fields...

> 2. mongoimport --db db_name --collection collection_name --type csv --file /var/www/export.csv --fields field1,field2,field3  --upsertFields field1,field2,field3

**NOTE:**
1. If you working in production environment, dealing with huge database then free up your mongo from load of queries and then export else it might get stucked.